# CSS width and height set to 100% for an input is larger that its container

Tags: css

I've got a bit of a css issue. I'm have a container div with a set size and an absolute position. Inside that I have an element of some kind and a div. the element can be a button or a input in my example. The button follows the rules and is 100% of the container, the input doen't follow the rules and is more than 100% of the container. Whats going on and how do I go about fixing it? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5D9z/1) - Click either widget to see its bounds.

CSS

```
.Object
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.Object .Cover, .Object button, .Object input
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:0;
}

.Object button
{
    padding: 2px;
}

.Object .Cover
{
    cursor: move;
    z-index:1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="Object" id="3b089a23-7732-e743-aea4-d9dcef359d4e" name="Unnamed Widget" style="height: 30px; "><div class="Cover"></div><input /></div>

<div class="Object" id="e1bc0640-e049-eda8-05ac-0a99c21c6fe1" name="Unnamed Widget" style="height: 30px; top: 10px; left: 210px; "><div class="Cover"></div><button data-click="">Unnamed Button</button></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman - The `INPUT` is larget than its container div and it should't be. The `BUTTON` is the same size as its container div, I would expect the `INPUT` to behave the same - its using the same css.

Comment: actually, the `input` follows the style 100px. I put a border on the container first, then on the `input` and it has the same width and height.

Comment: Why would the `input` follow the style 100px from `.Object` and not 100% from `.Object input`? Looking at my original jsfiddle and the element inspector in chrome, the computed width is 104px, the width is 100% and its parent div's width is 100px. I don't understand where the 104 comes from. The height of the input has the same issue as the width, and extra 4px. When using a button rather than input, there is no extra 4px.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it follows the style of `Object .input`. I changed the height and it behaved accordingly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The 104 px is caused by the box-model. When set to default it will take into account the borders and padding of the element, seeing as an input has default padding and borders (ipx in this case), it added up to 4 and made it "grow" out of its parent.

If you add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your input selector (I moved it to a standalone selector) and set your own border styles, it works as you desire :)

```
.Object input
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*border: 0;
    padding: 0;*/
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K5D9z/13/

Hope it helps.

Note: afaik IE6, 7 won't work as expected, but you can just use a conditional comment and set its width/height differently.

Comment: Its odd that the button didn't do the exact same thing. I hardcoded a 2px padding on the button (you can see it in the css) just to check if padding was the issue... The button stayed in bounds, the input doesn't. Either there is a bug or each element is treated differently for some odd reason.

Comment: Old post, but thanks - I've never seen 'box-sizing' before, and this bug has bothered me for years!